# A question about ‘After verb-ing, while …, main clause. ’？

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> Four days after setting out, while the Titanic was sailing across the icy waters of the North Atlantic, a huge iceberg was suddenly spotted by a lookout.

After verb-ing, subject do/did something. I know this knowledge. But in the sentence above, it is **After verb-ing, while subject one was doing something, subject two did something.**. It is **subject one** do the thing in **After verb-ing**, but **subject one** was in **while** clause.

So, is the sentence at the beginning right？

Comment: Yes, the sentence is correct. It could also have been written '...one of the lookouts spotted a huge iceberg'.

Comment: Correct.  After verb-ing clause applies to both subject one and subject two. *Four days after setting sail...* the Titanic was still sailing and a lookout was spotting [an iceberg dead ahead].